# Using Drag and Drop in iOS and mobile apps

Tags: ios, iphone, html, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I want to make an application in iOS using DnD of HTML5 that looks something like this: http://html5demos.com/drag.
But, heard that DnD is not yet supported by major mobile browsers. Also, if this is not an option, can i use HTML5 canvas to achieve the same?

Thanks

Comment: jQuery UI has support for drag-drop

Comment: Okay..Good that jQuery supports it.